# Creating SVN Repo and Accessing from within a CentOS 7 Machine

Tags: svn, centos, repository

We have a CentOS 7 machine where multiple users are working in some project. We want to create a local svn repository which can be accessed from within CentOS server.

The normal svn commands such as "svn checkout" always needs an URL
such as "svn checkout http:///svn/repo/path/."

Is there a way to use this commands locally without http such as "svn checkout /svn/repo/path/".

It's a very basic question but I don't seem to find answer of it. If anybody has any help, will be very thankful...

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to use the local `file://` access protocol to work with a repository without deploying any Subversion server at all. See https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#setting-up-a-local-repo and https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls.

However, you need to deploy a server if the repository has multiple users. See the following information in [SVNBook](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.recommendations):

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea of having all of your users
> access a repository directly via file:// URLs. Even if the repository
> is readily available to everyone via a network share, this is a bad
> idea. It removes any layers of protection between the users and the
> repository: users can accidentally (or intentionally) corrupt the
> repository database, it becomes hard to take the repository offline
> for inspection or upgrade, and it can lead to a mess of file
> permission problems (see the section called “Supporting Multiple
> Repository Access Methods”). Note that this is also one of the reasons
> we warn against accessing repositories via svn+ssh:// URLs—from a
> security standpoint, it's effectively the same as local users
> accessing via file://, and it can entail all the same problems if the
> administrator isn't careful.